# GridBagLayout start Jbuttons from middle of the screen

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jlabel, gridbaglayout

I have 14 buttons in GridBagLayout. Problem is that buttons start from middle of the screen vertically, instead from start screen. Also what i want is to buttons be same size, and to add some space between.

[image: Sreenshot:]

Here is my code:

```
    private final int MAX_TABLES = 14;
    JButton [] buttonsTables = new JButton[MAX_TABLES];

    frame = new JFrame("FreshPos baza podataka");
    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

    //Main panel
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();        
    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

    //West panel;
    JPanel panelWest = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());     
    panel.add(panelWest, BorderLayout.WEST);

    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_TABLES; i++) {          
        buttonsTables[i] = new JButton(tables[i]);
        buttonsTables[i].setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Integer.MAX_VALUE, buttonsTables[i].getMinimumSize().height));
        panelWest.add(buttonsTables[i], c);
        c.gridy++;
        panelWest.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));                     

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the buttons the same size, consider using a GridLayout, one with a constructor that adds space between components:

```
new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 5); // variable number of rows, 1 column, 5 pixels between
```

If you absolutely must use a GridBagLayout, set the constraint's fill property to `GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL` or `GridBagConstraints.BOTH`, and set the anchor property to `GridBagConstraints.WEST`

For an example of creating a bunch of JButtons, putting them in a grid on the left of the screen:

[image: ![enter image description here]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ButtonsOnSide extends JPanel {
    private static final String[] BTN_TEXTS = { 
            "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday",
            "Sunday", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", 
            "July", "August", "September", "October","November", "December" };
    private static final int PREF_W = 1000;
    private static final int PREF_H = 800;
    private static final int GAP = 4;

    public ButtonsOnSide() {
        JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, GAP));
        for (String btnText : BTN_TEXTS) {
            JButton btn = new JButton(btnText);
            btn.addActionListener(e -> System.out.println(e.getActionCommand()));
            btnPanel.add(btn);
        }
        // wrapper panel to help center the button panel vertically
        JPanel wrapperPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        wrapperPanel.add(btnPanel);

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP));
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(wrapperPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_START); // add to the left side
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ButtonsOnSide");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new ButtonsOnSide());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

Comment: With new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 5); everything is fine, except i have too much space between components.

Comment: @NikolaBozic: then reduce the size parameter

Comment: @NikolaBozic: If you need more specific help, create and post a valid [mcve], code **we** can test. Also post a picture or an ascii image of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @NikolaBozic: for an example of a MCVE, please see the code I've posted above.

Comment: @NikolaBozic: hello? Please let me know if this helped or if problems with it. Please don't ignore our efforts though.